# PowerShell: Add Reference to COM Interface ID directly

Tags: powershell, com, virtualbox

Is there by any chance a posibility to create a reference to an Interface ID Directly.

I tried something in a syntax form like but didnt work ...

```
$CO = new-object -ComObject "System.__ComObject#{fafa4e17-1ee2-4905-a10e-fe7c18bf5554}"
```

This Interface id is from Virtualbox.VirtualBox itself
I know that I can reference it with VirtualBox.VirtualBox naturally.

Can you refernce interface ids directly .... ?? 
As long the Interface is Public I Think you can but i cant find any example . ??

Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my own problem by accessing it through:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetTypeFromCLSID('fafa4e17-1ee2-4905-a10e-fe7c18bf5554')
```

OR:

```
$Type = [Type]::GetTypeFromCLSID('fafa4e17-1ee2-4905-a10e-fe7c18bf5554')
$Vbox = [System.Activator]::CreateInstance($Type)
$Vbox.APIVersion
```

This answered my question; case closed :)